# Is $\sin \alpha \cdot \sin \gamma= \sin^2 \beta$ or $\sin \alpha = \sin \gamma = \sin \beta$?

Tags: trigonometry, triangles

Here is the question:

> $A$, $B$, $C$ are three points on a horizontal line through the base $O$ of a pillar $OP$, such that $OA$, $OB$, $OC$ are in $AP$. If $\alpha$, $\beta$, $\gamma$ the angles elevation of the top of the pillar at $A$, $B$, $C$ respectively are also in A.P, then $\sin \alpha$, $\sin \beta$ ,$\sin \gamma$ are in AP, GP or HP?

Here AP stands for arithmetic progression, GP for geomtric progression and HP for harmonic progression.

Here is my process which is fairly straightforward:
$$ 
\begin{align*}
    OA+OC &=2\cdot OB \\
   \implies  OP \cot \alpha + OP \cot \gamma &= 2 \cdot OP \cot \beta \\
  \implies   \dfrac{\cos \alpha}{\sin \alpha}+\dfrac{\cos \gamma }{\sin \gamma} & = 2 \cdot \dfrac{\cos \beta}{\sin \beta} \\
  \implies   \cos \alpha \cdot \sin \gamma + \cos \gamma \cdot \sin \alpha & = 2 \cdot \dfrac{\cos \beta \cdot \sin \alpha \cdot \sin \gamma}{\sin \beta} \\
    \implies \sin (\alpha + \gamma) = \sin (2 \beta) & = 2 \cdot \dfrac{\cos \beta \cdot \sin \alpha \cdot \sin \gamma}{\sin \beta} \\
   \implies  2 \cdot \sin \beta \cos \beta & = 2 \cdot \dfrac{\cos \beta \cdot \sin \alpha \cdot \sin \gamma}{\sin \beta} \\
   \implies  \sin^2 \beta & = \sin \alpha \cdot \sin \gamma 
\end{align*}
$$

Which proves that they are in GP.

However, here is my problem:

If I find the angles $APB$ and $BPC$ I notice that they are same ($\alpha - \beta = \beta - \gamma$). Which means $PB$ is angle bisector. After applying angle bisector theorem we get that $AP=PC$ but that can only happen if $A$,$B$, and $C$ coincide. Which tells that $\alpha=\beta=\gamma$ and that $\sin \alpha= \sin \beta= \sin \gamma$ and hence they are in AP, GP as well as HP.

Here is another approach I tried:
Let $OA=a$, $OB=a+d$ and $OC=a+2d$.

$$\tan 2 \beta= \tan( \alpha + \gamma)$$

where $\tan \alpha = OP/OA$, $\tan \beta = OP/OB$ and $\tan \gamma = OP/OC$
Putting the values of the above expressions in the form of $a$, $d$ and $OP$ and then simplifying we get $d=0$ which further confirms that $OA=OB=OC$.

Am I going wrong anywhere?

Edit: Sorry if I confused anyone, but angle of elevation can be thought of as the angle the pillar $OP$ subtends at the point $A$. So $\angle OAP = \alpha$.

Comment: yes, I think $OA=OP\tan \alpha$

Comment: Sorry if I confused anyone, but angle of elevation can be thought of as the angle the pillar $OP$ subtends at the point $A$. So $\angle OAP = \alpha$.

Comment: I think that you've correctly showed that if there are such three points $A,B,C$ which are on the same half line, then $A=B=C$. (In other words, if they have to be distinct, then there are no such three points.) By the way, you are implicitly assuming that $A,B,C$ are on the same half line. Since the question does not say that $A,B,C$ are on the same half line, I would say that It is possible that only $B$ exists on the opposite half line where $\angle{APB}$ is no longer equal to $\angle{BPC}$.